# Cannot find module ledger-api/state.js on chaincode instantiation

Tags: node.js, module, hyperledger, instantiation, chaincode

I'm trying to instantiate a chaincode after I installed it succesfully with the following command `docker container exec -it cli peer chaincode install -n mycontract p /opt/gopath/src/github.com/sacc -v 1.0 -l node` and when I try to instantiate it with this command `docker container exec -it cli peer chaincode instantiate -n mycontract -v 1.0 -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -c '{"Args":["org.myproject.com:instantiate"]}' -P "AND('Org1MSP.member')" -l node` I'm getting these erros messages on my peer logs

> UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycontract-1.0] func2 -> INFO 077 Error: Cannot find module './../ledger-api/state.js'
>
> UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycontract-1.0] func2 -> INFO 078     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
>
> UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycontract-1.0] func2 -> INFO 079     at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
>
> UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycontract-1.0] func2 -> INFO 07a     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
>
> UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycontract-1.0] func2 -> INFO 07b     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>
> UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycontract-1.0] func2 -> INFO 07c     at Object. (/usr/local/src/documentototal.js:17:15)
>
> UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycontract-1.0] func2 -> INFO 07d     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
>
> UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycontract-1.0] func2 -> INFO 07e     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
>
> UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycontract-1.0] func2 -> INFO 07f     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
>
> UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycontract-1.0] func2 -> INFO 080     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
>
> UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycontract-1.0] func2 -> INFO 081     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake. When we instantiate a chaincode we are creating a docker image for that specific chaincode, with the specfic name and version we give to it. Even if we make changes in it, that same image will always be used if we try to instantiate it using the same command. So if you are facing similar problems with chaincode instantiation I would adivise you run `docker image rmi $(docker image images dev-* -q)` and then try to instantiate your chaincode again. Hope this helps someone else.